# CXF 3.1.5 vs. 2.7.17 - Access SOAP via HTTP GET

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-ws

I've got a SOAP JAXWS WebService here that was running fine with CXF 2.7. It also included the feature that I simply could access it via an URL, for example...

```
http://localhost:8080/webservices/myService/someMethod?someParameter=1&someOtherParameter=2
```

...which would result in an XML response. Unfortunately, I had to switch to CXF 3.1.5 (because of compatibility problems with more recent Spring versions) and now this feature seems to be gone, the only answer I get now is...

> No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params
>   unknown

Has anyone an idea where I can re-enable this feature (while I personally don't need it, some other people accessing the service with their own tools may depend on it)? Perhaps I was missing some dependency when moving to 3.1.5...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is the URIMappingInterceptor that has been removed from the default chain (and the code, since it was deprecated, see the [migration guide](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/30-migration-guide.html)) for security reasons. Unfortunate for people who depend on the HTTP Get mapping it did... Of course I could re-introduce it, but there's still the hope that there is a better, security-aware way of doing it...

Comment: Thanks for finding this out - I'm running into a similar issue wherein a vendor calls one of our SOAP API's on JBoss EAP 6 with a GET and it works fine but with JBoss EAP 7, it's failing with 405, method not allowed.  Still researching a workaround.